# Image not resizing on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

In my app i set an imageView as a background image like this.

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundView.jpg")
backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

But when i rotate the simulator in the landscape mode, the image gets cut off. 
P.S. I also noticed that if i run my app in the landscape then it fits pretty well even if i rotate to portrait and back. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using frame

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

you need to use auto-layout

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundView.jpg")
backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant:0),
    backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant:0),
    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant:0),
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant:0) 
])
```